# Dispatchers.IO running on main thread?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines

Consider the following code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            with(Dispatchers.IO) {
                if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                    throw Exception("we are on the main thread, though Dispatchers.IO is used")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually that does throw the exception

> java.lang.Exception: we are on the main thread, though Dispatchers.IO is used

but why? Shouldn't `Dispatchers.IO` use a background thread?

(Hint: I am aware that in most cases I better use the ViewModel scope for coroutines, but that's not the question here - I want to understand why the current code throws the exception)

Comment: You probably wanted to use `withContext` to switch context, `with` is just a scope function.

Comment: ah, you are right! Please post as answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mistaken scope function with coroutine one:

[`with(Dispatchers.IO){ }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) - a blocking call where lambdas body is scoped (`this === Dispatchers.IO`)

[`withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) - suspending call executed in provided context (in this case it switches dispatcher) that returns a result to original context